# I am a victim of the Petya ransomware. Is there a solution to decrypt my disk?

Tags: virus-removal, decryption

My computer got encrypted by the Petya ransomware. After a long search I could not find a solution other than using file recovery software.

This helps a bit, but I am wondering if there is a way to completely restore my disk. I am not going to pay.

Comment: To improve this question you might want to add some telltale signs that a ransomware infection is from this particular malware. Most users have no way to tell the name of the particular malware which hit them which means they won't find this question.

Comment: I don't think there is a real infection, they are just collecting reps, which is ok here on SU if it is a good question that has not been asked before.

Comment: Looks like it's not a rep grab but publicity for the exploit, which is by the OP himself. I wouldn't begrudge it, it looks non-trivial and potentially useful :-)

Comment: It looks like this is a way to Remove the Decrypt the disk. Check it out [Petya Ransomeware Defeated](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/petya-ransomwares-encryption-defeated-and-password-generator-released/) Looks Promising.

Comment: I know it's not terribly relevant, but would you mind sharing how it happened? Perhaps it might help other users avoid this problem.

Comment: Can I have a picture of the message

Comment: @SuiciDoga http://nabzsoftware.com/types-of-threats/petya-ransomware

Comment: This is yet another reason why you should be backing up your data often. If you had a reliable backup, you could simply wipe the computer and restore. If you [don't care about your data enough to back it up](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-your-backup-strategy/), then why worry about recovering it from ransomware?

Comment: @BryanH You can care about your data (and even back it up) and still also care about recovering a system from ransomware.

Comment: @TylerH true, if we were perfect we wouldn't be vulnerable to malware in the first place.  If you can't be perfect it's nice to have options.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Fortunately, yes, there is a solution - I've written an application that would help with this.

Petya encryption has been reversed, analyzed and there is a solution to get the decryption key, just from the data on the encrypted disk.

The program code for key recovery is hosted on github:
https://github.com/leo-stone/hack-petya.

<del>If you can't or don't want to compile the program yourself,

there is an online service available:

https://petya-pay-no-ransom.herokuapp.com/

https://petya-pay-no-ransom-mirror1.herokuapp.com/ (if the first link is erroring for you)</del>

You will still need to have a little computer experience though, to get the necessary data off your disk.

Update: Service has been taken down, it wasn't used anymore.

Comment: This is why you should never write your own encryption.. though I suppose in this case it's fortunate that they did.  If they had used AES, there'd be no way to brute-force the key like this.

Comment: @vsz The authors of this malware encrypt the hard-drive at a hardware level, and wrote their own bootloader (!?!).  I'm sure they've heard of AES.  It's like as oakad says, they probably did this intentionally for maximum speed.

Comment: That Heroku app is throwing errors. Has it been taken down?

Comment: @MichaelHampton its possible its being overloaded with traffic, this question has managed to hit the featured list probably bringing in a lot of clickers.

Comment: Oh, the disclosure rule. I do *strongly* recommend you do so, if only cause I'm getting a ton of spam flags for a useful tool ;)

Comment: @leostone otherwise this question and answer may be considered spam, I.e. Unwanted advertisement.

Comment: The weakness is not the encryption, it is that the key must be stored somewhere and the criminals can't hope to keep a remote server that is under their control accessible for the life time of the virus, for the virus to store new keys on.

Comment: Could you add a basic explanation of what your code does? The answer is complete; I'm just curious and my school WiFi doesn't let me load GitHub repos that don't belong to me.

Comment: @QPayTaxes The author goes about it in an intentionally roundabout way -- You can plug the decryption routine into just about any constraint solver and have an answer in seconds ( http://pastebin.com/Zc16DfL1 )

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Avoiding standard crypto for performance reasons is rather silly. Unless you have *very* fast IO, the process will be IO bound. A single core should be able to handle between 1 and 3 GB/s on a modern desktop. More if you reduce the number of rounds.

Comment: Comments are not designed to have a conversation.  If you don't have a comment with regards to the answer itself, take your statements, to chat.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: You should ask that as a different question, but in short:  Yes, that is very common for schools and businesses.  They control all the machines so they can install their own root certs.

Comment: @IanRingrose Why not just encrypt that key using a public key and have the victim email the encrypted key along with payment?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Especially since standard algos are implemented in hardware these days...

Comment: Thank you! It might be an idea/suggestion to include the accompanying [Fabian Wosar](https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=fwosar)'s [Petya Sector Extractor](http://download.bleepingcomputer.com/fabian-wosar/PetyaExtractor.zip) (for windows, linked on [bleepingcomputer.com](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/petya-ransomwares-encryption-defeated-and-password-generator-released/)) in this answer.  PS: Hopefully someone will combine and share these 2 sources into a .com executable that can be added to a syslinux usb boot-stick (alleviating need to take out HD).